# Auto detect cell fromat using vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

When you type data in a cell, excel automatically detect format of typed data.
For example when you type 12:00 , excel change format to custom and h:mm
How can I do this with vba code that format automatically detect and change based on value in cell?

Comment: debug.Print selection.numberformat

Comment: if it's dependent on values in a cell, the format assigned to these cells can be puled into VBA if you want (see other comment). Or, do you mean you only have `String` data type values in your cells and you would want VBA to figure out what the automatically assigned format would have been?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I do this with vba code that format automatically detect and change based on value in cell?

You can use the `.NumberFormat` property

Example

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheet1

    With ws
        Select Case .Range("A1").NumberFormat
        Case "General"
            'Do what you want
        Case "hh:mm"
            'Do what you want
        Case... Whatever
            'Do what you want
    End With
End Sub
```